# Cannot find symbol in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting, initialization

I am getting the error now that *BookCollection.java:67: error: incompatible types
      collection[lastElement++] = b;*

Also am not sure if my constructor is set up correctly? The directions were:

*Constructor:
    Given a parameter specifying the limit on the collection size, an empty book collection is created using the given parameter. The parameter should not exceed the preset maximum size 200.*

Am I initializing my variables correctly then? An answer below helped me change my code, but although I do not get errors within my constructor, I feel as though it may not be correct according to the directions....

I'll paste the couple chunks of my code that pertain to the question.

```
public class BookCollection{

   //data fields, need complete
   private int limit = 200;
   //Array of type book
   private int Book[];

   //actual size of collection, initialized to zero. Must never exceed limit
   private int collection[];     

   private int lastElement;

   //Constructor
   public BookCollection(int l, int c[], int le,int b[]){
      Book = b;
      collection = c;
      limit = l;
      lastElement = le;
      int lastElement = 0;
         if(limit <= 200){
            Book[] collection = new Book[limit];
         } else{
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("CannotExceedLimit");
           }   
      }
```

ANNDDDD where I am getting the error:

```
   public void addBook(int b[], int c[]) {
       Book = b;
       collection = c;
       if (lastElement == collection.length) {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("CorrectionFull");
       }
       for (int i = 0 ; i != lastElement ; i++) {
           if(b.equals(collection[i])) {
             throw new UnsupportedOperationException("DuplicateBook");
           }   
       }
       collection[lastElement++] = b;
   }
```

Comment: You have a `int[]` variable named `collection`. That's the one you are referencing in your `addBook` method.

Answer (score 3):

You have not declared `i` as an integer in your `for` loop. So add the declaration with initialization. Replace this

```
  for(i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
```

with

```
  for(int i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
```

Comment: This is the smallest of the OP's problems :)

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
BookCollection[] collection = new BookCollection[limit];   //initialize array of 200
```

declares a *local* array. It gets destroyed as soon as you leave the constructor.

The collection that stays around is this one:

```
private int collection[];
```

It consists of `int`s, so when you try to do this

```
collection[i].add(b);
```

the compiler correctly complains that `int` does not have a method called `add`.

Good chances are, even declaring the collection as

```
private Book[] collection;
```

and initializing it in the constructor as

```
collection = new Book[limit];
```

is not going to help, though: unlike collections, Java arrays do not let you change their size dynamically, so you need to store an index of the last element of the `collection[]` array that has been set.

This leads to understanding that you need a loop for finding duplicates, and noting else: define an element `int lastElement`, set it to zero in the constructor, and rewrite the `addBook` method as follows:

```
public void addBook(Book b) {
    if (lastElement == collection.length) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("CorrectionFull");
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i != lastElement ; i++) {
        if(b.equals(collection[i])) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("DuplicateBook");
        }
    }
    collection[lastElement++] = b;
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I really do appreciate your in-depth response. The reason I declared the array _BookCollection[] collection = new BookCollection[limit];_ is because the the instructions said: _Constructor_:
_Given a parameter specifying the limit on the collection size, an empty book collection is created using the given parameter. The parameter should not exceed the preset maximum size 200_ I was under the impression I was following the instructions by doing this in my constructor. What could I do differently to follow these instructions?

Comment: @jSeesFor3ver You need to check `limit` to be less than or equal to 200, otherwise throw an exception. You should not be creating an array of `BookCollection` objects: it should be an array of `Book` objects (I edited the answer to reflect that). `int Book[]` should be removed altogether: it's an array of integers named `Book`, not an array of type `Book`.

Comment: I updated my code. First off, don't I need to pass b of type book, a variable of type collection, and a variable of type lastElement into my addBook method? And also, (look at my edit in my question above), it seems that I still get this error _error: incompatible types collection[lastElement++] = b;_

Comment: @jSeesFor3ver Why do you keep using `int[]` arrays? You don't need `int[]` arrays. And no, you do not need to pass a book collection into the `addBook` method, because the method belongs to a book collection object.

Comment: I kept using int[] arrays to try and get rid of the error in the addBook method. In my constructor, don't I need to pass all of my data field objects? And also, in the addBook method, I don't know how to get rid of the error _error: incompatible types collection[lastElement++] = b;_  since declaring b as an int[] type or vice versa creates incompatible type errors within that method.

Comment: @jSeesFor3ver You need to make `collection` a `Book[] collection` rather than `int[] collection` in the declaration.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41131/discussion-between-jseesfor3ver-and-dasblinkenlight)

Answer (score 0):

You did't declared `i` as a `int` type variable, make it as

```
for(int i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
     ^here
   //...
}
```